# Java for-loop is not waiting for the input

Tags: java

How can I make a program wait for my input, then proceed for next statement. All I want to do is input 1,2,3 and then see 1,2,3 as output.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i=0;i==3;i++)
        {
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        // Complete this line
        // Complete this line

        System.out.println(a);
        // Complete this line
        // Complete this line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about to use `scan.nextInt()` three times without `for` loop?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Don't do that, it's bad practice.

Comment: @Artemis I thought she/he wanted to take 3 inputs at once then print them all at once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To first do input, then output, you'll need two loops. In addition, your for loop condition was wrong:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            numbers.add(scan.nextInt());

        for (Integer num : numbers)
            System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your for loop won't loop

change this :

```
for(int i=0;i==3;i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

the for loop is divided into

```
for(counter variable; boolean statement; increment/decrement)
          {block of code;}
```

Now when you put i==3,

*First statement:* creates an instance variable i and assigns its value to 0

*Second Statement:*  i==3 shows false since i is 0 and not 3 so loop stops

The boolean statement should be something like i<=2 so that statement is true till i is 2 or below.

```
    for(int i = 0; i <=2; i++)
    {
         int a = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.println(a);
    }
```

The second statement will tell your program when to end the for loop,

For example if you insert !(i==3), the loop will run 3 times because the statement is true till i becomes 3

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to see each number separately, you could do this:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
String nums = a + "";
String numbers = nums.split("(?!^)");
for(int i = 0; i > 3; i++) {
    String num1 = numbers[i];
    System.out.println(num1);
}
```